# How to deserialize a binary file of lists and read it?

Tags: c#, serialization

My goal is to serialize a list of new structs and save it to the same file repeatedly(For example, whenever the list has 5 structs, append the new structs to the same file).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<struct_realTime2> list_temp2 = new List<struct_realTime2>(100000);

        // ADD 5 new structs to list_temp2 
        for (int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
        {
            list_temp2.Add(new struct_realTime2 { indexNum = num,
                                                  currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"),
                                                  currentType = "type" });
        }

        // WRITE structs
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Append))
        {
            var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            foreach (struct_realTime2 stru in list_temp2)
            {
                bFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, stru);
            }

            list_temp2.Clear() // empty the list
        }

        // READ structs
        var list = new List<struct_realTime2>();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
            {
                list.Add((struct_realTime2)bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream));
            }                
        }

        // PRINT OUT  structs in the file
        foreach (struct_realTime2 stru in list)
        {
            string content_struct = stru.indexNum.ToString() + ", " + stru.currentTime;
            Console.WriteLine(content_struct);
        }

        // WRITE list
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file_list.bin", FileMode.Append))
        {
            var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            bFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, list_temp2);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct struct_realTime2
{
    public int indexNum { get; set; }
    public string currentTime { get; set; }
    public string currentType { get; set; }
}
```

```
< the result >
C:\Users\null\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\bin\Debug>ConsoleApp6.exe
0, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.044207
1, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
2, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
3, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
4, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225

C:\Users\null\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\bin\Debug>ConsoleApp6.exe
0, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.044207
1, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
2, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
3, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
4, 2019-11-10 15:31:52.047225
0, 2019-11-10 15:31:55.700680
1, 2019-11-10 15:31:55.703627
2, 2019-11-10 15:31:55.703627
3, 2019-11-10 15:31:55.703627
4, 2019-11-10 15:31:55.703627
```

It works fine if I append each struct to the file and read them. But I want to avoid appending each struct to the file using a loop, and just want to append `the list itself` to the file repeatedly and read the file.

It seems appending the list works because whenever I run the program, the size of `file_list.bin` doubles. But how can I read `file_list.bin` and make a new list with the structs in the file?

I'd appreciate it if I could get some code for that.

Comment: Write struct - read struct. Write list - read list.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use JSON?

Comment: Are you sure you want to write multiplie lists, and read multiple lists ? It becomes a hierarchical strucuture ? You don't want your plain list, that you have now, any more ?
You have to define yourself, how you store your list. Usually you  store the number of items first, and than you iterate over each item. You can put it in a subroutine and call it to serialize it "as once", but you cannot avoid the iteration.
The only thing you gain, is you keep your File of Lists, (instead of a File with one List, literally a table).

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov I'd like to see how it is done if you can show me some example code.

Comment: @ mjwills It's been only a few days since I got to know about serialization. If I could, I'd like to use https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp, but I don't know how and I'm trying to understand how to use the built-in class library first.

Comment: @Holger What I concern the most is to save data to file real time without latency or overhead which could hinder data receiving. I don't mind iterating over lists of lists when I read files later, but I want to avoid using cpu resources when the program is receiving data (because it could miss data while saving it to file).

Comment: You open your file in "append" mode and you add items. That's the fastest way to do it and I don't see any point of latency or doing unnecessary things. Don't open/close your file on each write would be a tip. Lists of Lists is an additional complication (cause it's an extra, you save more than the items only).
There will be no guarantee, you are not loosing data, since the saving cannot be done in zero time.
If think you search for something like a Memory-Dump ? Just writing one big block ? Something like that does not exist.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for your comment. This is how I thought: (1) using ```structs``` is rather fast (2) I could use ```List``` to store ```structs``` before writing them to file (3) If I only save ```structs``` to file, I need to iterate over them -> it takes CPU resources (4) If I just save the whole list itself to file(appending), there's no need for iteration -> it takes less CPU resources -> it will decrease the chances of not receiving data

Comment: @Holger Isn't it better to save one big block to file than to save smaller pieces to file, because it releases CPU and it works asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, it would be better, but this block is not available, it does not exist in memory. And no, it does not work asynchronously by iteself. It would be faster, cause you save a lot of calls of little functions, one for each little value.
If at all. The only thing you have en-bloc is an array of reference types. That you can consider as continues stream of bytes.
File.WriteAllBytesAsync might be what you want, but you need to have a byte[] for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSV

If you want to append data to existing file I recommend using a csv style serialization.

## BinaryFormatter

If you serialize a list (an array would be better) then the mirror of

```
bFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, list_temp2.ToArray());
```

is

```
var list = (struct_realTime2[])bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream));
```

This may not work if you append new data to an existing file (as opposed to overwriting the file each time).